# Find locations by name in Google Maps API within lat/lng bounds

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, flask

I have a list of named locations and a set of lat/lng bounds that I want to plug in to the Google Maps API and have it find the locations for me. The names can be very vague, like simply "the boarding school". Using the lat/lng bounds, is there a way I can get GMaps to find these vaguely named locations within the coordinates provided?

My application is web-based and powered by Python Flask in the backend. I've tried looking into Maps' Place Search, but it seems like it can only 'prefer' a certain area to search in, and with my vague place names, it doesn't do well:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.7741&key=XXXXXXX

This query has a bias covering part of Burlington, ON, but the result is in the neighbouring town of Oakville, significantly out of bounds. If you perform the search with the term "Burlington beach" instead however, it finds the beach that is within bounds.

I need the query to find the beach in Burlington, simply given the term "beach", and bounds that said beach falls within.

Edit: here are my HTTP requests+headers in both Chrome and Edge when testing the original query and Evan's smaller query (URL in comments):

```
==== Google Chrome: Original Request ====
:authority: maps.googleapis.com
:method: GET
:path: /maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.7741&key=
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,el-GR;q=0.7,el;q=0.6
cache-control: max-age=0
dnt: 1
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CIi2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIup/KAQioo8oBCOKoygEIl63KAQjNrcoBCMqvygEIh7TKARjwsMoB


==== Google Chrome: Evan's Request ====
:authority: maps.googleapis.com
:method: GET
:path: /maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.800879&key=
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-CA,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8,el-GR;q=0.7,el;q=0.6
cache-control: max-age=0
dnt: 1
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36
x-client-data: CIi2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIup/KAQioo8oBCOKoygEIl63KAQjNrcoBCMqvygEIh7TKARjwsMoB


==== Edge: Original Request ====
Request URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.7741&key=
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 /
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, */*; q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362


==== Edge: Evan's Request ====
Request URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.800879&key=
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 /
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, */*; q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-CA
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362
```

Comment: Hmm, can you just "manually" filter out results that are out of bounds?

Comment: @SuperStew the issue isn't that I'm getting both relevant and non-relevant results, it's that I only get non-relevant results if the search term isn't specific enough. The API is focusing more on returning results that it deems closer to the search term, rather than getting results that are within bounds.

Comment: I get `Burlington Beach, Burlington, Ontario, Canadá` with the above request, is this not the Burlington beach you're searching for? It's within your rectangle bounds.

Comment: In any case, for broad inputs I recommend you use smaller bounds so that you can ensure you'll get the right place you're looking for. Even then though note that very broad inputs can only go so far.

Comment: @evan, did you change the query at all? Are you simply running it in your browser or some other way? I get `45 West River Street Bronte, Oakville, ON` which is outside the bounds.

And the bounds are about 4km x 4km, which I don't think should be too broad for this to work. As for the beach example, there is only one shoreline within those bounds so the results should always be pretty close to each other.

Comment: I just tested your query on my home's laptop and it's now returning `1400 Lakeshore Rd, Burlington, ON L7S 1Y2, Canadá` but I swear at my work's computer I was getting the `Burlington Beach, Burlington` address. And this one I get now doesn't seem to match the one you get either. I'm making these queries on (chrome) browser in all cases. Also, while `45 West River Street Bronte, Oakville` is outside bounds, both addresses I got from your query are within bounds.

Comment: I'll test this query again tomorrow in the office, but in any case, the distance between your southwest and northeast points is 6.5km according to google maps which is still a lot, so the solution is to reduce the bounds area. What result do you get when you try the following request? (i get the burlington beach) https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/xml?input=beach&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,geometry&locationbias=rectangle:43.3145,-79.8236|43.3490,-79.800879&key=KEY

Comment: For a visual representation of your rectangle bounds vs mine check out this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t9c58ou6/

Comment: @evan: that's weird that it's returning different results on different machines. I'm doing all of my queries through Chrome as well. I tried your query and still got `45 West River Street Bronte, Oakville` even with the smaller area. Are you saying that after reducing the size of the bounds area, your result changed from `1400 Lakeshore Rd, Burlington` to `Burlington Beach, Burlington`?

Comment: Yes exactly, reducing the bounds changes the result i get (from 1400 lakeshore rd to burlington beach). I have some ideas on why these differences are happening but let me get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Update: I hard-refreshed the page for my original query in Chrome and started getting `680 Waterfront Trail, Hamilton`, which is even further away from the bounds. I tested in Edge and I also got this result. Both browsers return `45 West River Street Bronte, Oakville` on your query. I hard-refreshed the original query page in Chrome again and it went _back_ to `45 West River Street Bronte, Oakville`. My coworker is testing both queries in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on his machine and gets the same `Hamilton` address in all six cases. How is that possible?!

Comment: Thanks for your help so far @evan, I appreciate it. I'm starting to suspect that the perceived location of the source machine is factored in to the process somehow, which is causing the different locations to come up.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, and you're welcome, just trying to help out. Also, yep, I'm again getting Burlington Beach from my office's machine. Will give you an update and full answer later.

Comment: @CorporalHart Can you please provide the full HTTP requests including headers from all browsers in which you're making the calls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199705/discussion-between-corporal-hart-and-evan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inconsistency appears to be related to the following issue, reported in Google's Issue Tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822155

The language parameter influences the results you get from Place Search requests, and even more so with such generic/broad queries. So it's intended behavior for the API.

Potential alternatives to Find Place include using the [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) or the [Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) services. These are more appropriate for ambiguous queries and you can filter out results that are outside a given radius+location.

Hope this helps!