# Google Places Library Result inconsistent

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have been developing an application that utilises the following request to the findPlaceFromQuery method of the Places API:

```
{
    query: 'School lane',
    fields: ['place_id', 'name', 'geometry', 'formatted_address'],
    locationBias: {
      north: 54.615676,
      east: 0.086563,
      south: 53.637161,
      west: -2.103852,
    },
  }
```

The search query was purposely ambiguous and returned multiple results for days correctly focused inside the locationBias. However, without any changes this has become unusable as the result it returns no longer make sense. Where there were previously mutliple there are now only single results and they are not focused by the locationBias.

What has changed between making this request yesterday and today?

Comment: Single results seems to be intended behavior at least according to the official documentation: "Find Place from Query takes a text input and returns a place." https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#find_place_requests

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm more concerned about why the behaviour changes for the same query. This sometimes returns multiple results and sometimes single.

Comment: You can hit different servers at Google. Probably some of them work in unintended way, but only person from Google can address your question precisely I think.

Comment: Please see related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913128/find-locations-by-name-in-google-maps-api-within-lat-lng-bounds